# some problems on declaring and calling of fields in java

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to access some fields from some class, but i face trouble when i want to call them.

**This is the class which i have declared the fields :**

```
public class InfoOfFriends {

public static final String  Friends_List = "friends_list";
public static final String  userName = "username";
public static final String  STATUS = "status";
public static final String  PORT = "port";
public static final String  Ip = "Ip";
public static final String  UserKey = "userKey";
public static final String  Message = "message";
}
```

**And this is where i want to use them :**

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
{
    if (localName == "friend")
    {
        InfoOfFriends friend = new InfoOfFriends();
        friend.username = attributes.getValue(InfoOfFriends.userName);
        String status = attributes.getValue(InfoOfFriends.STATUS);

        friend.port = attributes.getValue(InfoOfFriends.PORT);

        if (status != null && status.equals("online")) {
            friend.status = InfoStatus.ONLINE;
            mOnlineFriends.add(friend);
        } else if (status.equals("unApproved")) {
            friend.status = InfoStatus.UNAPPROVED;
            mUnApprovedFriends.add(friend);
        } else {
            friend.status = InfoStatus.OFFLINE;
            mOnlineFriends.add(friend);
        }
    }

    else if (localName == "user")
    {
        this.userKey = attributes.getValue(InfoOfFriends.UserKey);
    }

    super.startElement(uri ,localName, name, (org.xml.sax.Attributes) attributes);
}
```

These parts have `errors` :

> friend.username = attributes.getValue(InfoOfFriends.userName);
>
> friend.port = attributes.getValue(InfoOfFriends.PORT);
>
> friend.status = InfoStatus.ONLINE;
>
> friend.status = InfoStatus.UNAPPROVED;
>
> friend.status = InfoStatus.OFFLINE;

Thanks for your time friends...

Comment: Why `if (localName == "friend")`? Based on `status.equals("online")` you seem to know proper way of comparing strings.

Comment: These are all final  fields. You can't modify final fields. If you want to assign new value to them, remove final modifier from their declaration

Comment: What are you trying to do in `friend.username = attributes.getValue(InfoOfFriends.userName);`? What kind of of field is `username`? What its modifiers mean?

Comment: He is tryin to do : friend.username = attributes.getValue("username"); Post your LogCat message!

Comment: When you say "these parts have error" ... what are you talking about?

Comment: in part: **friend.username** i want to put the value of InfoOfFreinds in friends.username arrey

Comment: "*I want to put the value of InfoOfFreinds in `friends.username` array*" `username` is not an array. It is a String reference, also final one so you can't reassign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all are you sure that `attributes` has the correct values?

and remember to use as string comparator the `equals()` method

```
  if (localName.equals("friend"))
```

instead of

```
  if (localName == "friend")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign new values to final fields. Remove the final keyword to resolve the error.

Also you made all of the fields static and use them as keys to retrieve stuff from Attributes, but at the same time you want to assign new values to them - probably a bad idea. Try doing a separate class with final static keys to use for the Attributes retrieving, and a separate Friend class to assign the retrieved values to.